# Unable to get menu to show in Bottom Navigation View

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I am attempting to create a bottom navigation however I am unsure what I need to do with my activity.kt code in order to make it appear.  I tried to follow the Google Codelab information and I got my menu and navigation bar set up correctly, however when attempting to add the Kotlin code nothing happens.

Here is my activity.xml code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#021F61"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"/>
```

Here is my menu.xml code:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_uni"
        android:icon="@drawable/uni"
        android:title="@string/university"/>

<item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_events"
        android:icon="@drawable/events"
        android:title="@string/events"/>

<item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_social"
        android:icon="@drawable/social"
        android:title="@string/social"/>

<item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_contact"
        android:icon="@drawable/contact"
        android:title="@string/contact"/>
```

And here is my (now empty) activity.kt code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class Home : AppCompatActivity() {



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)


}
```

Please let me know if this is something I can fix easily or if I should start with a fresh activity.  Thanks!

Comment: Since your navigation view seems to be inside a Constraint layout you should constraint it's sides to the parent. Also did you add your activity to the manifest file?

Comment: I did add it, however it is without any intent filters right now

Comment: Well you need to set them so that the framework knows which class to call and how.